# Python 3.x: enter one list as multiple parameters in a function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list with x number of parameters

```
[p1,p2,p3...pk]
```

and I need each item on the list to pass as a parameter so it goes like

```
function(p1,p2..,pk)
```

How can I do this without changing the function to recieve a list?
something like iter items, but I cant just go next(list) on each parameter because I don't know how much parameters i'm going to insert into the function

Comment: Use `function(*paramList)` where `paramList = [p1,p2,p3...pk]`

Comment: `function(*[p1,p2..,pk])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*` operator

```
list = [1, 2, 3, n]
foo(*list) # Function with n arguments
```

For example:

```
def foo(one, two):
    print(one, two)


list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [1, ]

# Call with list_* variable
foo(*list_1) # Print 1, 2
foo(*list_2) # TypeError, but requiere more arguments.
```

For solve `TypeError`, can use `*args` for has dynamic arguments in your function

Comment: After looking at your answer, I realise that the question might be interpreted in two ways - a) how to call it given a list, and b) how to make the function to recieve :D

Comment: The question was about calling a function given a list, I didn't realize the `*` simbol could be also when calling a function, that was the point of my question

Answer (score 0):

Python can take arguments as *args:

```
def foo(*args):
    print len(args)
    for x in args:
        print (x)

foo("a")
foo("a","b","c")
```

You can mix and match args and *args as well if you have a leading argument you need - something like `def foo(x,y, *args):`